# mod_rewrite: Rewriting / to cgi script

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, cgi, vhosts

Is there any way to rewrite a *GET /* to a cgi script with a parameter? Basically redirect / to /cgi-bin/scipt.cgi?123.

This does not work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ /cgi-bin/script.cgi?123 [L]
```

Instead it somehow rewrites / to /index.html/

Any way of doing this?

Comment: Where do you use those directives?

Comment: In my vhost conf, inside the VirtualHost directive.